# jquery.svg doesn't loads external svg file on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg

I have problem publishing a svg map on Internet Explorer 8. It works fine on all other browsers.
I am using Keith-wood jquery plugin.
What can I do to make it work on IE 8.

My code to load svg is:

```
$('#svgload').svg({
        loadURL: 'worldmap.svg',
        onLoad: function(svg) {
            $.each(land, function(name, value) {
                /// do stuff
                $("."+name).css("fill", "#F1551E");

              });

        }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/